# Update vcard automatically for every phones

Tags: android, iphone, updates, vcf-vcard

I am trying to create a vcard which can be updated automatically.
I found the some documentation on the wikipedia about the vcard and it seems to be possible to automatize the vcard updating.

> SOURCE    A URL that can be used to get the latest version of this vCard. SOURCE:http://johndoe.com/vcard.vcf

So I tried to create one vcard and I put the link of the updated vcard : 
SOURCE:http://www.example.com/me.vcf

I tried to import this vcard in the android phone and in the iphone.
I am failing to update informations.

Do you have any idea?
I am using the version 3.0

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation of this property is correct but no client that I know of make use of it.