# VCard update contacts

Tags: python, vcf-vcard

I have a CSV from Microsoft Exchange containing all the details I need in VCF. I am using Python to make a VCF from said CSV file, but the contacts won't update even though I have a valid UID (GUID from MS Exchange).

I am trying to import the CSV into Samsung A14 (fully updated) and Samsung S22 (fully updated).

I am attaching part of code that creates the structure of Vcard 3.0.

```
            file.write('BEGIN:VCARD\n')
            file.write('VERSION:3.0\n')
            file.write('UID:urn:uuid:{}\n'.format(uid))
            file.write('N:{};{}\n'.format(lastname, firstname))
            file.write('FN:{}\n'.format(name))
            file.write('ORG:{}\n'.format(org))
            file.write('TITLE:{}\n'.format(title))
            file.write('TEL;TYPE=CELL,VOICE:{}\n'.format(tel))
            file.write('EMAIL;TYPE=PREF,INTERNET:{}\n'.format(email))
            file.write('LABEL:{}\n'.format(label))
            file.write('END:VCARD\n')
```

Do you have any experience with updating contacts with VCF? Either Version 3.0 or 4.0?

- I have tried setting the UID to "12345" and on the importing screen it showed the new, updated information but after pressing Import I can still see old information.
- Tried using Version 4.0 which has CLIENTPIDMAP, but I can't import VCard Version 4.0. Name (N) has addition empty field, Label moved to ADR, TEL and EMAIL have slightly different structure -

```
            file.write('BEGIN:VCARD\n')
            file.write('VERSION:4.0\n')
            file.write('CLIENTPIDMAP:{}\n'.format(uid))
            file.write('N:{};{};;;\n'.format(lastname, firstname))
            file.write('FN:{}\n'.format(name))
            file.write('ORG:{}\n'.format(org))
            file.write('TITLE:{}\n'.format(title))
            file.write('TEL;TYPE=cell,voice:{}\n'.format(tel))
            file.write('EMAIL;PREF,INTERNET:{}\n'.format(email))
            file.write('ADR;LABEL="{}":;;;;\n'.format(label))
            file.write('END:VCARD\n')
```

- Read similar post about this issue ([Update vcard automatically for every phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788259/update-vcard-automatically-for-every-phones)) and from my understanding Android/iOS does not support UID in VCard 3.0. Anyone managed to update contacts with VCard 4.0?